# CakePHP belongsto like %%

Tags: cakephp, model

i need some help with these, I can't seem to be able find anything on internet.

I have a model

```
public $belongsTo = array(
      'Group' => array(
          'className' => 'Group',
          'foreignKey' => 'group_id',
      ),
      'Audit_type' => array(
          'className' => 'Audit_type',
          'foreignKey' => 'audit_type',
      ),
      'User' => array(
          'className' => 'User',
          'foreignKey' => 'auditor',
      ),
  );
```

but I need to be able to find Group with a like, because now in group_id i have multiple id like `145,125,123`

is there any way i can find it with a LIKE??

Update:

the table groups is a tree behavior table, is tree behavior from cakephp
now  the table that has multiple ids, is a table that has audits, and i need this audit to be part of multiple groups.

Comment: Have you thought about what would happen if you have an id of '12' and one of '123'?  Using a LIKE to find is almost always the last resort unless you're specifically building a search or something.

Comment: Yes, though that's the least of problems with storing multiple IDs in a single foreign key.

Comment: is there any other aproach to this??, or hwo would you guys recomend me to to this?? I'm out of options, i was thinking on making another table with the id and ids of the groups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DON'T store multiple id's in the group_id field!

Rather than a BelongsTo relationship, it sounds like you need CakePHP's [Has And Belongs To Many relationship](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasandbelongstomany-habtm).

But whatever you do, don't store multiple id's in the one foreign key field. That would be enough to give [Codd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codd%27s_12_rules) a heart attack!

Comment: how can i do it then since i really need this to have multime groups. the groups table is a tree behavior table

Comment: and i need it to be multiple grups

Comment: Update your question to include a full description of the relationships you're trying to model. What belongs to a group? And give more info on the tree-ness of what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use a "LIKE" for finding multiple IDs.

Do it like this instead:

```
$this->Group->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'id' => array('145', '125', '123')
    )
);
```

It will use MySQLs "IN".

Comment: I think I misunderstood... I guess it was hard for my brain to accept someone would try to LIKE a comma separated list of IDs in a should-be-int field.